# Finiteness of the set of zeros

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Please help me with the following problem:

Let $f$ be a continuous function, linearly bounded, i.e.

$$x+A<f(x)<x+B$$

We also now, that there exists an $x_0>0$ such that

$$f(x)=x+C,\quad x>x_0.$$
Let $g$ be a probability density function supported on $[0,\infty)$.
We can assume that $g$ may be as smooth as we want.

Fix $\gamma\in(0,1)$ and $d>0$.

The problem, bothering me for a very long time is how to show that the $h(x):[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$h(x)=-1+\gamma g(0) f(d+x)+\gamma\int_{0}^{d+x}f(y)g'(d+x-y)dy$$

has only finitely many zeros.

I actually show that for $x$ large enough $h(x)<0$, so **I need to show that this equation has only finitely many zeros on any compact interval $[0,x_1]$**

Comment: If $h'(x)$ is bounded, then $h(x)$ has only a finite number of zeros on any finite interval.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true. As a counterexample consider $f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$. We have $f'(x)=2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})$, so is bounded on $[0,1]$ but $f(x)$ has infinitely many zeros on $[0,1]$

Comment: Good point. My intuition did not see the function being squeezed to zero. Upvoted.